# ZenCoding in PHPStorm: how to make XML tags self-closing?

Tags: xml, phpstorm, emmet

I am using the Zen coding-alike stuff in PHPStorm for my XML documents. I find it to be very useful.

The only thing is that most of the tags I write should be short (self-closing) tags. Zen however, by default, creates long (opening and closing) tags. When doing HTML, Zen has intelligent knowledge of what tags should be long or short (i.e. `br` expands to `<br />`, while `div` extends to `<div></div>`.

Most of my elements can be written as long tags as well as short tags, my preference depends on whether I want that node to have children. How can I distinctively describe whether a tag should expand to a short (self-closing) tag or a long (open+close) tags?

// edit: Nobody? I've looked around the internet quite a bit, no joy so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure for XML, but for HTML I managed to change, for example `<img>` to `<img />`. You can set this on "Settings > Live Templates", then select ZEN HTML, ZEN CSS or ZEN XSL to edit whatever you want.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Try this http://blog.kaelig.fr/post/23222600612/zen-coding-en-xhtml5-sous-sublime-text-2
I had the same problem, I changed it and its works for HTML 5 :)

with This code in editor.py on line 220

```
if view.match_selector(pos, 'text.html'):
    if 'xhtml' in view.substr(sublime.Region(0, 1000)).lower():
        return 'xhtml'
    else:
        return 'xhtml'
else:
    return 'plain'
```

Comment: The question has never been related to Sublime Text, but to JetBrains PHPStorm.